# Regular Expression Match

Tags: php, regex

t=**vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug**

where the bolded area is the 42 character token

so far I am using this [^(t=)]\S{42}, but it is matching all strings, how do I get it to just match that from the source page from here view-source:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opQ9GzRe5qs

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you link to doesn't appear to contain the string you are searching for? But to match that string anywhere in the page then you would need...

```
/t=\S{42}/
```

I don't see any need for character classes `[...]` or parenthesised sub patterns...?

**EDIT#1**

However, if you are trying to extract that 42 char token then you *will* need a parenthesised sub pattern...

```
/t=(\S{42})/
```

**EDIT#2**

An example of extracting the token. I've changed this from 42 to 43 chars, since all your examples do seem to include a token of 43 chars.

```
// This is just some example text from which we want to extract the token...
$text = <<<EOD
SomeText=jkasdhHASGjajAHSKAK?asdjladljasdllkasdjllasdasdl
asdjasiSTARTHERE;t=vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug%3DENDHEREasdasd
SomeMoreText;t=ThisIsTooShort%3Dklaksj
EOD;

if (preg_match('/;t=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{43})%3D/',$text,$matches)) {
    // Match... vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug
    echo 'TOKEN: '.$matches[1];
} else {
    // No match
}
```

I've changed the pattern to be more restrictive, rather than any non-space char. It is now any letter, number, underscore or hyphen. It must now end in `%3D`, and there is a semicolon (";") before the "t=".

Comment: the token is generated everytime the page is loaded & is 42 in length, so i need to grab this string after t=

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question... are you trying to _match_ that character sequence (as stated in your question), perhaps using `preg_match()`? Or are you wanting to _extract_ the 42 character token? It would be an idea to paste the text you are trying to match, since that page does not contain that pattern.

Comment: it is an token that is generated everytime someone loads the page, so unable to paste exact match for it, however i want to extract that token, and the token has the following pattern, it starts with t=, ends with %3D and is 42 in length, hope i am making sense, the text above was a example of the token generated

Comment: that token was extracted but now it extracts all t="43 characters", how to put in regex that the pattern has to end with %3D?

Comment: I was just after an example of what you are trying to match against... including text before and after the pattern. eg. What appears _before_ the "t=" - this might affect the pattern you need to match. Yes, the exact token varies. I've added an example. Is it 43 or 42 chars?

Comment: there are more then 1 match for this regex so i need the end char to have only 1 match, right now all these strings are matching t="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/opQ9GzRe5qs/hqdefa; ect. but the correct token is in this part ;t=vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug%3D, so it needs to search for end chars i think

Comment: What is before the "t="? Matching for \S (anything other than a space is probably too much as well). What chars appear in the token? I can make a guess... I'll update my answer...

Comment: u0026amp;sw=0.1\u0026amp; is before the t=, characters in the token seem to be any number any letter and _ and - characters

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used php's regex engine, but unless it goes against the posix standard and every other regex engine on the planet,
`[^(t=)]` will match any character except a `t`, `=`, `(`, or `)`. So your regex will match that followed by 42 non-whitespace characters. It matches your string because you actually have 43 characters in the token.  What you probably meant was `^t=\S{43}$`, or something along those lines, it probably depends on what you're doing with it.

Comment: forgive me but since I am new to regex, I have been using this http://regexpal.com/ to test the expressions that were stated here, but both answers given don't seem to match, the string  t=vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug

Comment: ok, now it seems to be grabbing all the strings with t=, so how to have it so that the end string is %3D?

Comment: `$` matches the end, and none of `%3D` are special characters (as far as regexes go), so `%3D$` will match a string that ends in %3D.

Comment: it shows more then one match however for this, so how to create the expression so from this line ;t=vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug%3D, it extracts just this token vjVQa1PpcFMYuRsz10_H-1z41mWWe8d6ENEnBLE7gug